# Multithreading with sql query using php and pthreads or other library

Tags: php, curl, pthreads

I want to simulate bids at auction, in about 30 bids on 1 second. But I don't know, what does class I have to use? Stackable or Pool? I use https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads.

Comment: Apart from providing completely insufficient amount of information, the very fact you can't determine which class to use is a clear indicator that threads aren't for you. There are numerous examples on that repository which you can literally copy paste into your code to simulate stuff, but seeing you can't determine which one to use just says that threads aren't for what you want to do. There are simpler ways, and if your question is how to simulate 30 requests in 1 second - there are numerous ways. It all depends on *what* you're trying to "hit" 30 times in a second. Post some code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I spread my code, but it is return 2,5 bids per 1 second. `$worker = new Bot('localhost:3307', 'auctionc_1', 'XeiThahg8z', 'auctionc_1'); $worker->start(); while($j++<=5000) { $stack[$j] = new Work(true); $worker->stack($stack[$j]); usleep(100); }`

in Work class I declare CURL for bidding, in Bot class I initialize it. And I declare in Work class some method for connection to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `stream_socket_client`

This is about as close to multi-treading as PHP can get.  It can handle 30 connection and be able to return the results on each socket.

**Create the bids**

```
$bids[] = 'makebid/item8349/?bid=1.00';
$bids[] = 'makebid/item8350/?bid=1.50';
```

**Create the "processes":**

```
$timeout = 20; 
$result = array(); 
$sockets = array(); 
$buffer_size = 8192;
$id = 0;
foreach($bids as $bid){
  $stream = stream_socket_client("auction.com:80", $errno,$errstr, $timeout,
      STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT); 
  if ($stream) {
    $sockets[$id++] = $stream;  // supports multiple sockets
    $http = "GET /$bid HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: auction.com\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($stream, $http);
  } 
  else { 
    echo "$id Failed\n";
  } 
}
```

**Monitor the bids:**

```
while (count($sockets)) {
  $read = $sockets; 
  stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $timeout); 
  if (count($read)) {
    foreach ($read as $r) { 
      $id = array_search($r, $sockets); 
      $data = fread($r, $buffer_size); 
      if (strlen($data) == 0) { 
        echo "$id Closed: " . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
        fclose($r); 
        unset($sockets[$id]);
      } 
      else {
        $result[$id] .= $data; 
      }
    }
  }
  else { 
    echo 'Timeout: ' . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
    break;
  }
}
```